# Change index font size with imakeidx

Tags: fontsize, indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

I know I can change the index font size combining the `imakeidx` package with the `idxlayout` package like this:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}
```

However I was wondering if it was possible to use just the `imakeidx` package (maybe with the `othercode` key of the `\indexsetup` command).

Comment: Yes, `\indexsetup{othercode=\small}` will do. Notice, however, that this setting applies to all indices.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Can you post the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One can modify the index formatting with `\indexsetup`, that takes as argument a list of key-value pairs; in your case the key is `othercode`:

```
\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
```

The code given as value to the key is inserted just before the index body is typeset, so this doesn't influence the header.

Note, however, that the effect is global and will affect all indices.

Answer (score 9):

While it is possible to reduce the index fontsize using only `imakeidx`, the space between index heading and first entry will be somewhat larger than that produced by a fontsize switch after a "normal" heading. If you use `idxlayout`, the spacing will be the same. The following MWE contains both variants; comment/uncomment the respective lines and compare.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

% Variant A 
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}

% Variant B
% \indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\section*{Unnumbered section}

\footnotesize

foo, 1\index{foo}

\clearpage

\normalsize

\printindex

\end{document}
```