# How to change text size and display in index

Tags: indexing

I would like to ...

1. **decrease** the font size -> solved with [Change index font size with imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123652/change-index-font-size-with-imakeidx)
2. and **reduce the indent** for the second line (numbers 11,13 and 13) -> solved with [Long indexes style with imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362651/long-indexes-style-with-imakeidx/362655#362655)

This is the code I'm using :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=2, title=Indeks]

\begin{document}

\kant[1-2] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[3-6] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[7-9] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[10-13] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[14-17] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[18-21] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\kant[22-25] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something,
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} is writing something,

\kant[26-29] Demetrius\index{Demetrius} is writing something
Dhimitër\index{Dhimitër} finished writing.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And this is the result :

[image]

Comment: Related to [Change index font size with imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123652/124842)

Comment: No I still have the indent issue.

Comment: Second problem could be fixed with [Long indexes style with imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362655/124842). You could modify `0pt` to something else.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I needed. Any idea what should be done with the question now ?

Comment: I think there is no need to write a new answer. I will vote to set both answers as duplicat. 1 question is solved with [Change index font size with imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123652/124842) 2. question is solved with [Long indexes style with imakeidx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362651/124842)